# Run-time of these recurrence relations

Tags: runtime, computer-science, relation, master-theorem, theorem

How do you calculate a tight bound run time for these relations?

- T(n)=T(n-3)+n^2
- T(n) = 4T(n/4)+log^3(n)

For the first one I used the substitution method which gave me n^2 but wasn't right and the second one I used Masters Theorem and got nlog^4(n) which also wasn't right. A thorough explanation would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

for the First Recurrence, we can solve it by recurrence tree method

T(n)=T(n-3)+n^2

a) here we see that the number of sub problems are n/3(every i Subtract 3 from n so in n/3 steps we will be reaching the last subproblem).

b) at each level the cost is n^2

therefore the time complexiety is roughly (n/3)*n^2= (n^3)/3 which is O(n^3)

Coming to the second recurrence relation

T(n)=4T(n/4)+log^3(n)

Here we can't apply Master's theorem because n and log^3(n) are not comparable Polynomial times
we could have applied master's theorem(Corollary for strictly logarithmic bounds) if we had something like nlog^3(n) because it is greater strictly by log times

correct me if i am wrong here